# How to call React method from index.html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I am working on a web app that is in React with Typescript where I need to do certain things i.e. one of our system needs to communicate with our web app through a Javascript function. I will get certain data in the Javascript function (index.html). I need to call a react function from script tag in html. How can I do this.

I try to call, but it didn't worked.

```
<script>
function func1(filename){
 CallReactMethod(filename); //Not working
}
```

Comment: Is this react function in your backend? It sounds like `index.html` isn't a page generated by react - it might be helpful to convert it to a react page instead, which will make adding methods like this easier.

Comment: @Dakeyras - CallReactMethod is a React method, which I need to call from index.html.